# Comparing 2 Pair Data with Loop in Ms Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is anyone can help me, pls take a look at the **picture** i attached.
I want to compare 2 pair of data from 2 different excel file, **Station** (left file **column** **B**) with **Station** (right file **column** **A**) **AND** **Time** (left file **row 1**) with **Tendancy** (right file **Column F**).
The left file is the report that im about to finished, the right file is the reference data. If the station and the time data is match each other, it will filled with **"1"**, if not it will stay **empty**.
The data will start filling from cell **C2** until **Z32**. Im stuck with FOR and IF looping i used. And here's the example:

1. **Cell C2** will filed with **"1"** bcs there is station **2000001 (cell A2)** at **00UTC (cell F2)** on the **right file**.
2. **Cell E2** will stay **empty** bcs there is station **2000001** **BUT NOT** at **02UTC** on the **right file**.
3. **Cell C3** will stay **empty** bcs there is station **2000002** **BUT NOT** at **00UTC** on the **right file**.

[image]

```
Dim countSM As Long
Dim countSS As Long
Dim countWM As Long
Dim countWS As Long
Dim resultCol As Long
Dim resultRow As Long

Dim lastSM As Long
Dim lastSS As Long
Dim lastWM As Long
Dim lastWS As Long
Dim lastRCol As Long
Dim lastRRow As Long

lastSM = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastSS = wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastWM = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastWS = wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastRCol = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRRow = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For countSM = 2 To lastWM
For countSS = 2 To lastWS
If wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(countSM, "B") = wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(countSS, "A") Then
    For countWM = 3 To lastWM
    For countWS = 2 To lastWS
    If wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, countWM) = wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(countWS, "F") Then
        For resultRow = 2 To lastRRow
        For resultCol = 3 To lastRCol
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(resultRow, resultCol) = "1"
        Next resultCol
        Next resultRow
        Next countSS
    ElseIf wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, countWM) <> wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(countWS, "F") Then
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(resultRow, resultCol) = ""
        Next countWM
    End If
    Next countSS
ElseIf wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(countSM, "B") <> wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(countSS, "A") Then
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(resultRow, resultCol) = ""
        Next countSM
End If
```

Comment: @braX i just updated the question with the code i got so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a code that may work for you. Just count how many rows got the station and UTC value you want to check. If the answer is zero, leave the cell empty. If not, then return 1.

My code is designed on **same workbook** but it can be adapted yo work with 2 different workbooks easily.

My fake dataset:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub test()
'<------>
'
'
'
'
'YOUR CODE TO OPEN BOTH FILES
'
'
'

'<---->



Dim LeftSheet As Worksheet
Dim RightSheet As Worksheet
Dim MyData As Range 'range to store the data (right file)
Dim LR As Long 'Last row of left file, column Station
Dim LC As Long 'Lastcolumn of left file, (whatever UTC it is)
Dim i As Long
Dim zz As Long
Dim MiF As WorksheetFunction
Set MiF = WorksheetFunction
Dim MyStation As String
Dim MyUTC As String


'Probably you'll need just to adjust references to worksheets from different workbooks

Set LeftSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destiny")
Set RightSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")

'we store all data into array
Set MyData = RightSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'data starts at index 2, and we want data from columns 1 and 6 on the range
'Columns 1 and 6 mean columns A and F

'I guess maybe you'll need to adapt this too.
With LeftSheet
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'we count how many rows got the station and tendancy value (intersection) on the right file
    ' if the count is 0, do nothing. If not zero, return 1 on the cell
    'our references will be always at column 2 and row 1
    
    For i = 2 To LR Step 1 'we start at row 2 on left file
    
        MyStation = .Range("B" & i).Value
        For zz = 3 To LC Step 1 'we start at column 3, that means column C
            MyUTC = .Cells(1, zz).Value
            If MiF.CountIfs(MyData.Columns(1), MyStation, MyData.Columns(6), MyUTC) <> 0 Then .Cells(i, zz).Value = 1
        Next zz
    Next i

End With


'clean variables
Set MyData = Nothing
Set LeftSheet = Nothing
Set RightSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output after executing code:

[image]

Comment: Dang! I was too confused by the looping conditions inside the looping.
Thankyou so much, u opened my mind, ur code is so simple. thankyou so much

Answer (score 1):

Give this solution a try:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Type TWorksheetData
        WrkSheet As Worksheet
        LastRow As Long
        LastColumn As Long
    End Type

    Sub CopyCompare()
        'Organize the variables by referenced worksheet
        Dim worksheetData As TWorksheetData
        Dim sheet1Data As TWorksheetData
        
        'your solution will provide separate Workbooks for the code below
        'ActiveWorkbook (in my case) had both worksheets in order to develop the solution
        sheet1Data = SetupWorksheetData(Application.ActiveWorkbook, "Sheet1", sheet1Data)
        worksheetData = SetupWorksheetData(Application.ActiveWorkbook, "Worksheet", worksheetData)
        
        Dim refData As Dictionary
        Set refData = New Dictionary
        
        'Load the reference data (key = station, value = collection of UTCs)
        Dim station As Long
        Dim countRow As Long
        For countRow = 2 To worksheetData.LastRow
            station = CLng(worksheetData.WrkSheet.Range("A" & CStr(countRow)).Value)
            If Not refData.Exists(station) Then
                refData.Add station, New Collection
            End If

            refData(station).Add worksheetData.WrkSheet.Range("F" & CStr(countRow)).Value
        Next countRow
        
        'Load the UTC header columns from Sheet1
        Dim outputMap As Dictionary '(key = UTCXX, value = column Number)
        Set outputMap = LoadUTCHeaderColumns(sheet1Data)
        
        'Operate on the Sheet1 data to set the value
        For countRow = 2 To sheet1Data.LastRow
            station = CLng(sheet1Data.WrkSheet.Range("B" & CStr(countRow)).Value)
            Dim utcRef As Variant
            If refData.Exists(station) Then
                Dim utc As Variant
                For Each utc In refData(station)
                    If InputSheetHasUTCEntry(utc, outputMap) Then
                        sheet1Data.WrkSheet.Cells(countRow, outputMap(utc)) = "1"
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next countRow
    End Sub

    Private Function InputSheetHasUTCEntry(ByVal utc As String, ByVal outputMap As Dictionary) As Boolean
        InputSheetHasUTCEntry = False
        Dim utcRef As Variant
        For Each utcRef In outputMap.Keys
            If utc = utcRef Then
                InputSheetHasUTCEntry = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next utcRef
    End Function

    Private Function LoadUTCHeaderColumns(ByRef sheetData As TWorksheetData) As Dictionary
        Set LoadUTCHeaderColumns = New Dictionary
        Dim columnHeader As String
        Dim outputCol As Long
        For outputCol = 1 To sheetData.LastColumn
            columnHeader = sheetData.WrkSheet.Cells(1, outputCol).Value
            If InStr(columnHeader, "UTC") > 0 Then
                LoadUTCHeaderColumns.Add columnHeader, outputCol
            End If
        Next outputCol
    End Function

    Private Function SetupWorksheetData(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetName As String, ByRef wrksheetData As TWorksheetData) As TWorksheetData
        SetupWorksheetData = wrksheetData
        Set SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
        SetupWorksheetData.LastRow = SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        SetupWorksheetData.LastColumn = SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End Function
```

Solution comments:

1. Loads static reference data from from sheet `Worksheet` (recommend a different sheet name)
2. Loads static column number information from `Sheet1`
3. There are lots of variables holding similar data for each worksheet used.  This indicates an opportunity for using a `UserDefinedType` (`TWorksheetData` in this case).  This organizes and reduces the number of variables to declare and track.

#1 and #2 uses a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to retain and correlate static information (requires adding a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime).

Other comments:

1. (Best Practice) Always declare `Option Explicit` at the top of modules.  Forces all variables used to be declared.
2. (Best Practice) Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) - there is a lot of repeated expressions in the original code.  This is especially important with Strings.  More could be done with the solution provided, but (for example) you will notice that the worksheet name strings only appear once.

Comment: I added the Microsoft Scripting Runtime, it solved. But i got another error 9: Subscript Out Of Range on the "Set SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet = wb.Sheets(sheetName)"