# I got an "Error 9: Subscript Out Of Range" on codes

Tags: excel, vba

help, i got error 9: Subscript Out Of Range on the

```
Set SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
```

How to fix it? And here's the code that i got...

```
Private Function SetupWorksheetData(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetName As String, ByRef wrksheetData As TWorksheetData) As TWorksheetData
    SetupWorksheetData = wrksheetData
    Set SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    SetupWorksheetData.LastRow = SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    SetupWorksheetData.LastColumn = SetupWorksheetData.WrkSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

I copied it from here: [Comparing 2 Pair Data with Loop in Ms Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661750/comparing-2-pair-data-with-loop-in-ms-excel-vba/67665713#67665713)

Comment: What is `sheetName`? Is it correct? Is there a space at the end of the actual sheet name? You will also have problems with the next 2 lines, because you are specifying a workbook for your sheet variable and you cannot do that. You just leave off the workbook variable in that case because the sheet variable already knows what workbook it's in.

Comment: What is a `TWorksheetData`?

Comment: I can't input all the code, bcs of my description is less than the code... Here's the original code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661750/comparing-2-pair-data-with-loop-in-ms-excel-vba/67665713#67665713

Comment: Short answer: because there is no worksheet in the workbook passed via `wb` named whatever the passed value of `sheetname` is.  If you want more help than that, you'll have to give us more information about how you are calling this function

Comment: @chrisneilsen pls take a look at this, all the code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661750/comparing-2-pair-data-with-loop-in-ms-excel-vba/67665713#67665713

Comment: Why did you post the link to the tutorial again?

Comment: @braX I just looking for an answer that i stucked for a week :(

Comment: But are you going to address any of the other comments which already explain where the problems are? Or are you waiting for something?

Comment: For debugging, you can put  `Msgbox sheetName` after the first row in that code (a new second row). And when you run the code, compare the message to the sheets you have. Does it match?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber the first message and the second message is different...

Comment: If you get multiple messages, the one just before the error is the relevant one. Compare that to the sheet names in the worbook.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Both of the messages is same with both of sheets name